# Error when trying to test app from xcode on device

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi guys i have just started studying in making apps however there is an error occuring everytime i try to test it on my ipod touch

here is the full error

> CreateUniversalBinary
>   /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app/tweejump
>   normal "armv6 armv7 armv6" cd
>   /Users/scerip/Desktop/haqu-tweejump-9a05d35 setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /usr/bin/lipo -create
>   /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/tweejump.build/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.build/Objects-normal/armv6/tweejump
>   /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/tweejump.build/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.build/Objects-normal/armv7/tweejump
>   /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/tweejump.build/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.build/Objects-normal/armv6/tweejump
>   -output /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app/tweejump
>   /usr/bin/lipo:
>   /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/tweejump.build/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.build/Objects-normal/armv6/tweejump
>   and
>   /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/tweejump.build/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.build/Objects-normal/armv6/tweejump
>   have the same architectures (armv6) and can't be in the same fat
>   output file Command /usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1

I have tried several different solutions that i have found here on stackoverflow and on the internet but none of them seem to work... any ideas?

best regards Jens Gleerup

EDIIIIT: new error popping up:/

CodeSign /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app
cd /Users/scerip/Desktop/haqu-tweejump-9a05d35
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Jens Gleerup (4JA43UQ24Y)" --resource-rules=/Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/tweejump.build/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.build/tweejump.xcent /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app

/Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

From `have the same architectures (armv6)` and `"armv6 armv7 armv6"` I guess your project has `armv6`, `armv7` and another `armv6` in its `Architectures` setting.

Open the Build Settings of your project and remove the second armv6 if it's there.

Comment: Thank you alot for the help!:) worked out that error however now there is a new one popping up! i have written the full error above in the actual thread